# rvm installation fails on powerpc ibook g4

Tags: command-line, rvm, powerpc

I am trying to install ruby version manager on a g4 ibook running 10.4 but I receive two error messages right off the bat when I try to run the first command:

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
bash: line 6: set: errtrace: invalid option name
bash: line 13: conditional binary operator expected
```

I am new to ruby, rails, and fairly inexperienced with the command line too. I've done a bit of searching and have seen other people having problems installing a specific *version* of ruby on a powerpc using rvm, but no other examples of someone having a problem installing rvm first of all.

Does this seem like a powerpc issue? Or is there something simple with the command line that I am missing here?

I have also searched on these specific error messages but haven't found any solutions yet. Oh and I should also add that I have xcode installed and I also installed macports because I thought that might help...but it hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause of the error you're getting is your bash version is far too old to be used with any relatively new RVM version. Also, the likelihood of you being able to easily compile rubies on a G4 now is very low. You'll likely end up needing to compile many tools and libraries from source which you'll have to do from the command-line. Finding the right combination of library versions that both support your arch and are still available for download might not be as easy as it sounds. Much of the ruby compilation on OS X depends on libraries that come with Xcode. So, you might hit a wall there too with rubies now requiring newer libraries that can be provided with a version of Xcode that can be installed on your system.

You can try upgrading your bash version and/or use a much older version of RVM, although, I don't remember RVM ever working on 10.4. Or, you can try to compile everything from source, including Ruby. You'll might be able to get Ruby 1.8.6, maybe 1.8.7 working but anything higher is very unlikely.

Good luck =/

Comment: It seems that I may have bitten off more than I can chew for a beginning rails project. I think I'll try to make it a little easier on myself and switch to an intel-based desktop that is using 10.6. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Since you're running 10.6 now, you might want to give JewelryBox (http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com) a try. It's the official OS X RVM GUI (I'm the author). If this helped answer your question, could you accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Remear, I've accepted the answer and I'm going to give JewelryBox a try. Thanks!